# How to access the edit method of a nested resource with simple_form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-resources

I have 3 models: `Book`, `UserBook`, and `User` (from devise). `User` and `Book` are linked though `UserBook` with a `has_many:users through: :user_books`.

I've been trying to access the edit and destroy methods in `user_books` using a simple form in `books#show` to change a boolean value `have_or_want` from `false` to `true`. These are the models:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :users, through: :user_books
  validates :title, :author, presence: true
  validates :rating, inclusion: {in: [1,2,3,4,5], allow_nill: false }
end

class UserBook < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 has_many :user_books
 has_many :books, through: :user_books
end
```

The idea is that you can look a book in `books#show` and an if statement decides which of three `simple_forms` is shown:

If there is no `UserBook` linking the `current_user` to the book there will be a radio button which if you want to add it to your own book collection (`@user_book.have_or_want: true`) or add it to your reading list (`@user_book.have_or_want: false`). This bit work and a new `UserBook` is created correctly using `user_books#update`.

I am now trying to have a form for when the book is on the users reading `list(@user_book.have_or_want)` to give the option marking the book as read (change `@user_book.have_or_want` to `true` with `user_books#update`) or to remove the book (`user_books#destroy`).

Also a third form for if it is in the book collection (`@user_book.have_or_want: true`) to remove it by deleting the `@user_book`.

In the routes `UserBook` is nested in `Book`.

The if statement and simple forms in `books#show` looks like this and the first part works.

```
<% if current_user.books.exclude? @book  %>
<%= simple_form_for [@book, @user_book] do |f| %>
<%= f.input :have_or_want,
:collection => [[true, 'Add to Bookshelf'], [false, 'Add to resding 
list']],
:label_method => :last,
:value_method => :first,
:as => :radio_buttons %>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<% elsif @book.user_books[0].have_or_want == false %>

<!-- If is is on the reading list you can add to bookshelf(changes 
have_or_want to true) or can remove from reading list (delete 
user_book instance) -->

<%= simple_form_for [@book, @user_book], url: 
book_user_book_path(@book, @user_book), method: :patch  do |f| %>
<%= f.input :have_or_want %>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
<% else %>

<!-- It is on the bookshelf so option to remove - user_books#destroy?  
-->

<% end %>
```

I have tried several ways to do the second part and this is my best guess at the moment. There error I get is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :book_id=>"1", :controller=>"user_books", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Also `@user_book` is a `user_book` with all values of nil.